# ASIHTTP upload white image

Tags: php, iphone, file-upload, asihttprequest, image-uploading

I'm using ASIHTTP to POST data to server, and all the data is received as it should

I'm uploading the image with

```
    [request1 setData:imageData withFileName:@"upload.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"Image"];
```

where imageData is NSData

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] ;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480)); 

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        CGSize kMaxImageViewSize = {.width = 100, .height = 100};

        //[self resizeImage:newImage newSize:kMaxImageViewSize];
        imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self resizeImage:newImage newSize:kMaxImageViewSize], 0.5); 

}
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return newImage;
}
```

this is how i re-size the image. The problem that I have is, when the image gets saved on server I just get a white image, blank one. IS it a server problem or maybe something I dont send form the app

**EDIT**
Here is my server code

```
$filename="upload";
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path .$filename.".png"; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "uploaded an image";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (newImagesTaken.size.width > 320 || newImagesTaken.size.height > 480) {
                                // resize the image
                                float actualHeight = newImagesTaken.size.height;
                                float actualWidth = newImagesTaken.size.width;
                                float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
                                float maxRatio = self.view.frame.size.width/self.view.frame.size.height;

                                if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
                                    imgRatio = self.view.frame.size.height / actualHeight;
                                    actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
                                    actualHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
                                }
                                else{
                                    imgRatio = self.view.frame.size.width / actualWidth;
                                    actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
                                    actualWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
                                }
                                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
                                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
                                [newImagesTaken drawInRect:rect];
                                newImagesTaken = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                            }    

                            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImagesTaken, 1.0);
     [request addData:imageData withFileName:@"ByDefault.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"Filedata"];



$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path .  $_FILES['media']['name']; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name'],$target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['media']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: not helping. From the way I can see it, this can be a server (php) problem

Comment: @Spire Yes ! if it still not working thn it there must be a problem at webservice end ? Do you have the code of php end ? I can sought this out for you. Thanks

Comment: Here is the best example with exceptional handling.                        http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/

Comment: Your uploading or trying to replace a file on server with the same name.

Comment: I have edited my code which contains php code at the end. Thanks

Comment: ti was a server error but thx for your interest in my problem